# Can I package SQL Server Express with my Visual Studio program deployment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I have created an application in Visual Studio that uses a .mdf database and executes SQL scripts on it. The program imports and exports reports to and from Excel. I want to be able to give this program to team members, but they get an error "error: 52 - Unable to locate a local database runtime installation. verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled."

I assume they get this error because they do not have SQL Server installed. Is there anyway I can include the minimum SQL Server components needed within my deployment? What is the minimum requirement? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you make it a web page?

Comment: Dan - Hm that actually sounds like a great idea. I have no experience with something like that though. Are there costs to having it?

Comment: You could also look at an embedded database system like sqlcompact or sqlite

Comment: Sorry, the URL was too long and got cut off.  Try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21383167/109122